# Creating an array whose elements are pointers to different arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, initialization, declaration

I'm trying to create an array of pointers. In this code, array 'p' is supposed to contain pointers to the other arrays 'a', 'b', and 'c'. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code. Any help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int a[3]={'4','1','3'};
    int b[3]={'a','1','3'};
    int c[3]={'y','1','3'};
    int *p[2];
    
    p[1]=a[1];
    *(p+1)= a+1;
    printf("%d",p[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For starters, `int *p[2];` --> `int *p[3];` This won't even compile: `p[1] = a[1];` because `a[1]` is an `int` and `p[1]` is an `int *`. What about: `int *p[3]; p[0] = a; p[1] = b; p[2] = c;`?

Answer (score 4):

To declare an array of pointers to these arrays

```
int a[3]={'4','1','3'};
int b[3]={'a','1','3'};
int c[3]={'y','1','3'};
```

you need to write

```
int * p[3] = { a, b, c };
```

In this declaration the array designators used as initializers are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements. That is it is the same if to write

```
int * p[3] = { &a[0], &b[0], &c[0] };
```

This expression statement

```
p[1]=a[1];
```

is incorrect because the left side operand has the type `int *` while the right side operand has the type `int`.

This statement

```
*(p+1)= a+1;
```

that is equivalent to the statement

```
p[1] = a + 1;
```

or to

```
p[1] = &a[1];
```

is correct.

In this statement

```
printf("%d",p[1]);
```

there is used an incorrect conversion specifier `%d` with pointer expression `p[1]`.

If you want to output the pointer expression `p[1]` then you need to write

```
printf( "%p\n", ( void * )p[1] );
```

If you want to output the pointed value by the expression `p[1]` you need to write

```
printf( "%d\n", *p[1] );
```

Or if you want to output it as a character you can write

```
printf( "%c\n", *p[1] );
```

Comment: Thank you! I took your suggestions and the program prints out 49, how do i just print out the 4?

Comment: @BersabehKifle It is the ASCII value of the character '1' stored in a[1]. To output it as a character you could write printf( "%c\n", *p[1] );